# Parallel loop counter in Julia

Tags: julia, parallel.for

In Julia, I would like to print out inside a parallel for loop the number of iterations the loop has completed.

Is this a safe way to do so, and/or is there a better way?

```
a = SharedArray(Int, 10)
counter = SharedArray(Int, 1)
arr = 1:10
tot = length(arr)
@parallel for i in collect(arr)
    a[i] = i
    counter[1] += 1
    println("$i/$tot")
    sleep(rand()) # simulate a variable amount of computation
end
```

Comment: IMO, this question is not include a clear problem statement.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that my doubt comes from the fact that I'm using a length-1 SharedArray as a counter, where all I want is one integer really. Is it safe to increase this counter inside a parallel loop? Is there a neater way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are not using the shared `counter` to print the iteration, but the integer `i`.
I'm assuming from your question that you are looking for a way to print constantly increasing iteration numbers within a parallel loop. This is not possible with asynchronous execution as you don't know the order in which the loop is executed.

As an example: let's say processor1 does `i=1` and it might take too long. While processor1 executes another processor might complete `i=2` and `i=3`. This would result in `i=2,3` printed before `i=1`.

> You can't really get around this problem as this parallel behavior
>   (processes taking over slow processes) is one the main benefits of
>   parallel computing.

Here are the examples:

```
># parallel sum with async execution
>sum_i =  @parallel (+) for i in 1:10
>  println(i)
>  i
>end

From worker 4:  8
From worker 4:  9
From worker 3:  5
From worker 4:  10
From worker 3:  6
From worker 2:  1
From worker 3:  7
From worker 2:  2
From worker 2:  3
From worker 2:  4
```

Note the wrong ordering above.

You can produce a constantly increasing list of integers if you pick one processor. These will only be the ones that particular processor sees, but this gives you a sort of indication of how much your function has done:

```
>sum_i =  @parallel (+) for i in 1:10
>  if myid() == 2
>    println(i)
>  end
>
>  i
>end

From worker 3:  5
From worker 3:  6
From worker 3:  7
```